# How can we apply real time validation in laravel using livewire, if we are using wire.model.defer on input?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use livewire real time validation, but i can't because i am using wire.model.defer to prevent loading each time, is there any way i can use real time validation with wire.model.defer on each input field ? any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

use simple way by `v-model` and check if accept your **rules** or not

Comment: `v-model` sounds like Vue, is that available in Livewire?

Comment: ofcourse you can use vue with livewire and you can integrated with laravel

Comment: Isn't the main point of Livewire to _not_ use Vue/React but PHP/Laravel to build dynamic interfaces?

Comment: oh i'm so sorry, that is correct